# Strange drop in active installs

Tags: android, google-play

I had 3 apps on the market for some time now. Two of them experienced a markable rise in active installations some weeks ago. One of them even had more active installs than downloads which was quiet surprising.

However some days ago, the active installations dropped to the level before the rise. Here are the graphs:

[image]

[image]

Did someone experience a similar behaviour? And what's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not receive the email from google? 
They realised their algorithm was wrong. They were counting updates.

This has happened to everyone, it now correctly report live installs

Comment: I can't remember receiving a mail. But this would explain the whole thing, as the rise began after I updated the apps.

Comment: Yeh, it's now correct and should continue to reflect actual live installs